# Calculate the Fourier Transform of $A(x)$

Tags: fourier-series

I want to calculate the fourier transform $\hat{A}$ of the following function:

$$A(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $\lvert x \rvert \le \frac{b}{2}$ } \\[2ex]
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

The fourier transform can be calculated by using the formula:

$$\hat{A}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}A(x)e^{-ikx} dx$$

I don't know how to deal with the condition $1, \space \space \space \text{if $\lvert x\rvert \le \frac{b}{2}$}$. How can I integrate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a piecewise function $A(x)$, you should break the integral into pieces also. The fact that the function you're considering is 0 outside of a range makes that easier.

\begin{eqnarray}\hat{A}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}A(x)e^{-ikx} dx=\hat{A}&=&\int_{-b/2}^{+b/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-ikx} dx\\
&=& \frac{1}{ik\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(e^{ikb/2}-e^{-ikb/2}\right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{k}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sin\left(\frac{kb}{2}\right)
\end{eqnarray}